# How to prepare my iOS app for the new iPhone 5 size?

Tags: ios, iphone-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with iPhone 5 screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396545/how-to-deal-with-iphone-5-screen-size)

Now that the iPhone 5 is out and it has a different resolution and screen size, I would like to find some information on how to prepare for it.  Is my app going to resize automatically if it's mostly standard views (table views, image views) or will I have to check for the screen size and resize accordingly?  If the app supports iOS 5+ will it always be in the box?