# Do I have to create two views for iPhone 4S and 5

Tags: ios, user-interface, interface-builder, iphone-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with iPhone 5 screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396545/how-to-deal-with-iphone-5-screen-size)

The new iPhone 5 has a 4 inch display.

In IB, I want to make my iPhone 5 view different to my 4S. The 4S version needs a scroll view, but the 5 doesn't.

How can I create two views (with all connected outlets) in the same xib, one which is 3.5 inches, and one which is four inches?

Do I have to create a totally new xib and include it for iPhone5 ?

I am just a bit unclear on the approach.

(I have seen other questions which don't answer this particular question)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deal with iPhone 5 screen size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396545/how-to-deal-with-iphone-5-screen-size)...
... and ...and of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396143/how-to-add-iphone-5-large-screen-support-to-ios-apps-in-xcode, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396892/how-to-prepare-my-ios-app-for-the-new-iphone-5-size

Comment: @H2CO3 Nope, I dont see any answers on that that answer my question. They are just telling the OP to add an image that makes it compatible for iPhone 5 (removes the black bars)

Comment: Yes I searched through the documentation and used Google for like 30 minutes. The iPhone 5 is particularly new, so it was hard to find answers to my question

Comment: I didn't "call people names' - this question has been asked many times in the last 4-5 days. If you really used Google for 30 minutes yet you found nothing, you really missed something. (And, btw, 22k is not that much...)

Comment: Not to mention any answer will involve working with materials that are still under NDA until the 19th.

Comment: Sort iOS 6 or iPhone tagged questions by newest and look between now and the Apple press event. I promise you'll find the answer :) This question has been asked 15-20 times already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like a completely different view for the iPhone 5 then yes you should use a different nib, however I would advise that you need not use different nibs and instead use autolayouts to autosize your views accordingly so that you can have 1 codebase working across multiple devices.