# Apps in iOS having design issues

Tags: iphone, ios6, iphone-5

I have an app in app store.In iPhone 5 i am facing a issue related to the look and feel of the app.If the app is opened in iphone 5 then there is a black space coming at the top and bottom of the screen.

I have checked in various apps present in the app store and it is happening to all the apps.Has anyone faced such an issue.I just wanted to know,if anything needs to be done from developer side,such as images of different dimensions like the one's given for retina and normal display or Apple would come up with a default aspect ratio.

I am seriously stuck up and client is asking if there is any fix for that.

Thanks

Comment: iPhone 5 has a 4" screen, you need to fix view height for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543264/screen-height-compatible-in-iphone5-and-iphone4/12544075#12544075

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a developer pls be aware of things happening around! All the existing apps in appstore will run in letterboxed mode unless it is remodified for iphone 5. You have to use Xocde 4.5 to develop apps for iPhone 5 with ios 6 compatibility.

If your client need to fix this, you can charge him to make the changes. :)