# Preparing an app to run on both 3.5'' and 4'' without autolayout

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I'm writing an app which has to have vertical sliders and is supposed to run on both iPhone4 and iPhone5. I had to turn off autolayout because otherwise vertical sliders wouldn't display properly.

Is there a way to create a layout which will look good on both 3.5'' and 4'' screen without autolayout?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I support the taller iPhone 5 screen size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397811/how-do-i-support-the-taller-iphone-5-screen-size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you disable auto-layout, the view system switches to using "auto-resize masks", which is auto-layout's predecessor.

You'll have to either learn how auto-layout works or how auto-resize masks work. There is plenty of documentation for both systems.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible to do that. You can either code your UI by yourself and use `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size` as your screen size reference or work with Storyboards and use the AutoSizing (not AutoLayout) guides.