# What to check in order to support the iPhone 5's longer screen?

Tags: ios, iphone-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with iPhone 5 screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396545/how-to-deal-with-iphone-5-screen-size)

The iPhone 5 comes with a longer screen (1136x640 vs 960x640), what should be taken care of in order to support the new (and old) resolutions gracefully?

Answer (score 0):

XIB resources in the first place, they need either be stretchable, i.e. use correct autoresizing settings, or be redesigned.

Answer (score 0):

Splash screens, screen shots, nib files for starters. Additionally, I am willing to bet Apple will handle all these mismatches of sizes elegantly (at least initially) to allow devs time to catch up with these new requirements (like how they initially handled non-retina app assets).