# iPhone 5 [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uikit, uiscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)
>   [How to deal with iPhone 5 screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396545/how-to-deal-with-iphone-5-screen-size)
>   [What to check in order to support the iPhone 5's longer screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398098/what-to-check-in-order-to-support-the-iphone-5s-longer-screen)

With the new screen size on iPhone 5, anyone know or guess what `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height` will return in an app running on iPhone 5? On all other iPhones, including Retina, it returns `480` - I assume it will now return `568` ?

Or, will it run in the "centered, letterboxed" mode unless some other configuration is made in the app to "allow" the full iPhone 5 resolution?

Comment: valid point. I suppose an upgrade to Xcode is necessary?

Comment: Since iOS 6 is still under NDA, we can't post the answer to these questions here.  Ask on the [Apple Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/community/ios/ios6beta), or wait until the 21st, or try it in the latest simulator.

Comment: @robmayoff If you don't mind my asking does the NDA lift on the 21st, or on the 19th when iOS 6 goes public?

Comment: I suppose it will be lifted on the 19th if that's when iOS 6 will be released.

Comment: To be clear, are you saying that my question is an iOS 6 issue as opposed to an iPhone 5 issue? I made no mention of iOS 6 and am merely referring to the added pixels in the iPhone 5, announced today. How do I get the latest simulator and is it the new screen size?

Comment: The iPhone 5 is also still unreleased ^^, as is its simulator.  You can get the simulator if you are a registered developer but discussing it is still off-limits (I know...it's tough ^^;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the height is 568.  If you want to remove "letterboxing", please see this post:
[iPhone 5 letterboxing / screen resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398819/iphone-5-letterboxing-screen-resize)