# Do apps need to be modified for the iPhone 5's screen?

Tags: ios, iphone-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with iPhone 5 screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396545/how-to-deal-with-iphone-5-screen-size)

The iPhone 5 has a bigger screen than all previous models (4 inches instead of 3.5). How will this affect current apps that were designed for the original screen when they're displayed on the iPhone 5?

I ask because I am withholding the launch of a new app of mine and am wondering if I need to make modifications for iPhone 5 screen-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existing apps will run in a compatibility mode, and will be presented in a "letterbox" format.