# Views are portrait in older versions

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a problem here and am not able to come up with answer why my app is behaving so.
I made application using XCode 4.5+ and iOS6 and have set my application to work in landscape mode it was working and running fine till I tried to run it in previous version like iOS 5.1 simulator or below all views are in portrait mode :(

Comment: for iOS5 you have to implement the method `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation` in your view controllers

Comment: Please search first, there are many similar posts regarding orientation changes in iOS 6.0, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404556/interface-orientation-in-ios-6-0).

Comment: @Irene my app is working well in iOS 6 but I am not able to understand the reason why my app is in portrait mode in Lower versions whereas in landscape mode in iOS6, when I have set entire application to landscape mode(I have set it to landscape from my xib files) and also in supported Interface orientation

Answer (score 0):

You can try defining this method in your controllers:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
  return ( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)ç
}
```

This plays the same role as `shouldAutorotate` for iOS6.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by tkanzakic `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOr‌​ientation` solved my problem with lower versions thanks a lot :)