# How to set only portrait orientation for view controller in iOS?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6, view, landscape

My project has many view controller (.xib file).
I want: a view controller can only have portrait orientation. However an other view controller can only have landscape orientation. or a view controller can have both portrait and landscape orientation.
Now I want a view controller only have landscape orientation (no portrait orientation). Please help me. Thanks you.

Comment: Check this one [Interface orientation in iOS 6.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404556/interface-orientation-in-ios-6-0). Let me know your response after trying this.

Comment: Go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37085341/how-to-set-certain-view-controller-to-be-landscape-and-portrait-and-certain-to-b/37086217#37086217

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation);
}
```

**UPDATED:**

You can do this by creating category of UINaviagationController

code for .h file is

```
@interface UINavigationController (autorotation)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate;
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations;
```

and code for .m file is

```
 @implementation UINavigationController (autorotation)

    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
    {

        UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
        [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
        return YES;

    }

    -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;

    }
    @end
```

Comment: You need to modify the code according to your suitability. I have just given you the generalized form.

Comment: I try to set for UIView. I am using iOS 6