# How to set certain view controller to be landscape and portrait and certain to be landscape only ? (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, view, landscape, portrait

How can I set certain view controller to be landscape and portrait and certain to be landscape only? Thanks .

Comment: can i know whether your app supports landscape mode and portrait or it supports only portrait mode?

Comment: the app support portrait but some view needed to be portrait and landscape

Answer (score 2):

Step 1. Create a subclass of UINavigationcontroller named like CustomNavController
Step 2. initialise CustomNavController instead of UINavigationController in AppdDelegate.

Step 3. override following method of UINavigationController in CustomNavController

```
-(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{

    if([NSStringFromClass([[[self viewControllers] lastObject] class]) isEqualToString:@"ViewAsset"]){
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

where ViewAsset is name of class which you need in both mode.

for more interesting tutorials check out https://appengineer.in/

Comment: I have a problem i successfully set the orientation but when i present modally from another landscape controller to potrait controller it show landscape.

Answer (score 1):

1) Select the "device orientations" that you want in your project from the "Deployment Info" in the "General" tab.

2) In your view controller class, use this code:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask) supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

}
```

3) For view controllers that you want to support both orientations:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask) supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;

}
```

Comment: I have a problem i successfully set the orientation but when i present modally from another landscape controller to potrait controller it show landscape.

Comment: @TOP10NEWS -  See if this link can help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/27561781/6080920