# What I need to do, to remake/port my universal iOS app for iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, interface-builder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the steps required to migrate existing apps to the iPhone 5 widescreen display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/what-are-the-steps-required-to-migrate-existing-apps-to-the-iphone-5-widescreen)
>   [How to deal with iPhone 5 screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396545/how-to-deal-with-iphone-5-screen-size)

I have universal app for iPhone/iPad, but as you know, 12th of September Apple presented us new iPhone 5 with new 4 inch display. How to name and make .xib files for iPhone 5? Now there are black lines instead

Comment: @MartinR is this a reason to downgrade my question? Do you see there answer for MY question?

Comment: I did not downvote your question! I have marked it as duplicate because the same question has been asked several times in the last 20 hours. Most of the questions have been closed because the iOS 6 SDK is (as far as I know) still under NDA.

Comment: @MartinR that is correct. The NDA will remain in effect until iOS 6 goes public on the 19th.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I upgraded an universal app by taking the following steps:

Autorotation is changing in iOS 6. In iOS 6, the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method of UIViewController is deprecated. In its place, you should use the `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` and `shouldAutorotate` methods. Thus, I added these new methods (and kept the old for iOS 5 compatibility):

```
   -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
               return YES;
    }

    -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
               return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;    
    }
```

Then I fixed the autolayout for views that needed it. Remember to test the autorotation in iOS 5 and iOS 6 because of the changes in rotation.

Copied images from the simulator for startup view and views for the iTunes store into PhotoShop and exported them as png files. The name of the default image is: `Default-568h@2x.png` the size is 640 x 1136 and the screen size 320 x 568.

I have dropped backward compatibility for iOS 4. The reason is that this new Xcode does not support armv6 code any more. Thus, all devices that I am able to support now (running armv7) can be upgraded to iOS 5.