# Designing for the iPhone 5 Screen And For Devices With Smaller Screens

Tags: ios, iphone-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with iPhone 5 screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396545/how-to-deal-with-iphone-5-screen-size)

We know that apps that weren't designed for the new screen will run with a border around them. But what about apps that were designed for the bigger screen? How should we implement apps that we want them to work with both the new bigger screen and older devices' screens? How do apps deal with smaller screens when designed for iPhone 5, or rather, how should the programmer deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developers will start using a new size-system called constraints. This way apps will fit the small and the big screen.

I hope this was the answer you're searching for!