# Handling the larger device size of iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with iPhone 5 screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396545/how-to-deal-with-iphone-5-screen-size)

Watched the iPhone 5 keynote and yes the device height and a resolution of 640 X 1136. So I saw they showed how existing apps which work on that. But I believe if we use native components like tab bar, navigation bar etc. will work fine. But how about custom tab bars, navigation bars and controls which resides relative to the device orientation. So these are my questions.

1) How to handle custom layouts which has custom tab bars, navigation bars, relative contents etc.

2) Welcome screen. We will need 2 sizes right now. So in iPhone 5 do we need another 2 more for normal and retina?

3) If you carefully watched the keynote seems iPhone 5 will cut some portion of view from left and right so there is no any additional change in the app development. Has anybody noticed that?

Comment: In your third point, the view does not cut of portion left and right. iOS will add a black bar above and below the app to make it fit the original view size. there is nothing cut off.

Comment: @rckoenes Thanks. Then it still looks not nice when it comes to new size then. Isn't there any better way to cope up with the device size?

Comment: Well no not really, the reason beging some developers have made the layout of there apps absolute and have not set the autoresizingmask correctly. I've even done some animation with absolute positioning. Thus make the app displayed in the 320x480 resolution wil solve the issue for apps that do not support the new resolution. Downside are the two back bar above and below. Just make sure you set the autoresize mask correctly and include the new `Default-568h@2x.png` and you app will resize to the new resolution.

Comment: Ya the main reason not to use the auto resizing mask was iPhone had a constant device size and most of the people developed apps in one orientation. In future this wont be the case then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) This depends on how you laid them out, you might need to adjust how you set the frame, change autoresizing masks etc, or if iOS 6 only is an option you could move to auto layout. Without knowing your code I cant give much more detail

2) There is no non-retina iPhone 5 so you only need 1 more `Default.png` size, named `Default-568h@2x.png` (btw adding this new sized default image is the trigger for iOS to show your app without letterboxing, so for some apps this is the only change which will need to be made)

3) This is the letterboxing I mentioned, it is what all current apps will do on the iPhone 5 until they are updated with a new default.png

Comment: Thanks @wattson12. Yes it was one of my mistake. We will need only one additional welcome screen. Even if you have auto layouts still some developers will like to customize some functionality to iPhone 5. In that case it will be hard like that without an universal app concept.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that all existing apps will work on iPhone 5 and you will just have the black borders. However you will now have the capability to tailor apps to the bigger screen size. I imagine that there will now be a new sized .xib or storyboard that will match the size of the iPhone 5. You will be able to put an if statement in the app delegate to choose which .xib/storyboard to load based on the screen size. unfortunately now I think we will have to create multiple .xib/storyboard files, similar to how universal apps are made at the moment. The file loaded is selected based on the device.

Hope this helps

Comment: No there is no new XIB for the iPhone 5, you just need to set the autoresizing mask correctly for the view and the view will resize to the new screen size.

Comment: I believe yes it should be auto resizing masks.

Comment: Interesting, perhaps my information was wrong. I will look into this further and feed back.