# I have a xib file that I am trying to resize for iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have tried many different methods, if anyone can give me a method that worked for you please help me.

Comment: Autolayout worked for me, tell me wich ones you have tried and can cross from the list

Comment: autolayout, retina 4 display , and some source codes.

Comment: The carrier and wifi signal is  not on top it is posted about an inch way from the top.

Comment: In that case follow Max's answer, it means your app has not been enabled for iPhone5.

Answer (score 4):

Don't create a separate Xib for iPhone 5. Instead, add a splash image named `Default-568h@2x.png`. That will identify your app as one that supports iPhone 5 metrics.

When the app is loaded - either on an iPhone 5 device - or on the sim with Retina 4-inch display, you will see your app running in full 568 pixel height mode.

You may see some empty spaces, or buttons in the wrong place, and so on. That's because you have not configured the autosizing properties correctly in Interface Builder. Be sure to do that, using the controls below to specify the "sticky-ness" of the the controls, and how they should expand into the additional space.

[image: Autosizing controls]

Answer (score 0):

There are a privies question u should do a good search before u ask ;)

here some good answer i'm sure it will help u :

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420521/handling-the-larger-device-size-of-iphone-5)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582283/how-can-i-create-xibs-for-both-iphone-4-and-iphone-5-using-xocde-4-5)

if i understand correctly what u wanna this will be 100% helpful , otherwise write more explain.

Comment: I believe my problem is the status bar.

Comment: @JickLick u did not accept any answer, did u still have any problem ??

Answer (score 0):

Here you can apply my logic.

you may create the separate XIB for separate device as iPhone(normal),4inches and iPad device.No need to resize XIB to any device specific.just create separate XIB

```
    - (void)createSeperateXIB
      {
       YourViewController* yourVC  
      if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
      {
        if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)//for 4inches device
        {
        yourVC  = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController_iPhone5" bundle:nil];
       }
       else{//normal iphone/iPod device
          yourVC  = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
       }
      }
       else{//for ipad 
       yourVC  = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
}
```

}

Comment: trying to avoid coding, this should be simple but it isn't