# How can I get my app ready for the iPhone 5

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with iPhone 5 screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396545/how-to-deal-with-iphone-5-screen-size)

Apple just announced the iPhone 5 with a 4 inch screen and a 16:9 aspect ratio. Of course, they only give developers two weeks to scramble to update their apps without being able to test.

I'd like to update my app for the iPhone 5's new big screen, but there's nothing on Apple's developer site about the iPhone 5 or making your apps ready for a larger screen. It would be a pain to have to write my own logic for testing whether the device is an iPhone 5 and then displaying a custom storyboard file for it.

Does anyone know how the new sizing works or if there are any hidden Xcode for this?

Comment: Xcode 4.5 GM is still under NDA. Please post that kind of question on ADC forums.