# Specify images to 4 inch iOS device

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6

I facing some trouble while updating my application to be compatible with 3.5' and 4.0' displays(iPhone 5).When i add graphics(png image) to my view,if the device is 3.5' display everything is showed correctly but when i launch the view in a 4.0' device the image remains the same as 3.5' inch(ex:myimage@2x.png - 640x960px).So how can i change images when the device display is 4.0' so a 640x1136px image would be displayed?

More clearly:

1. Display = 320x480px   => my image.png
2. Display = 640x960px   => myimage@2x.png
3. Display = **640x1136px**  => myimage { **HOW DO DISCERN THIS RESOLUTION** } .png

Comment: Did you have any luck in getting something like this to work? I am faced with the very same problem right now and thinking of writing a category for UIImage that uses one of the UIDevice-categories from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396545

Answer (score 0):

Just drag the image you want to use in the splash screen box in the application summary. Maybe change window size to 4.0 in IB. Rest should be magic.

Also check this [iOS 6 apps - how to deal with iPhone 5 screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396545/how-to-deal-with-iphone-5-screen-size)

Comment: This is not about the default splash screen but a UIImageView inside a view!

Comment: How about autoresizingMask? `view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight` or `myimage568h@2x.png` ?

Comment: I believe resizing would downgrade the image quality,which is not an option.What i really want to know if there is any suffix to identify a 4'display image and display it.

Comment: i believe there will never be one, as its a different ratio. you could also try to take the 568h image for all and tell it to scale to fit or bottom, depends on the image. but thats what i did.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a blog-post that offers a solution by swizzling UIImage's `imageNamed`:
http://angelolloqui.com/blog/20-iPhone5-image-loading

It's not mine, I'm just posting it here in case somebody finds this question before they find that posting (like me).

Of course, your app might be rejected for using method-swizzling on framework-classes.