# How to tackle with varied screen sizes in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, screen, iphone-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with iPhone 5 screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396545/how-to-deal-with-iphone-5-screen-size)

iphone 5 has a different screen size and the others have different screen size. How do i program to make my app reliable for both usage?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IB then everything is done for you.

However, if you're putting custom objects on the screen then you will need to know which device you are putting them on. The way I've done it is so use:

> [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

And then if the height is 1136, it's an iPhone 5.