# How to make my app compatible with iphone 5's big screen?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)
>   [How to deal with iPhone 5 screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396545/how-to-deal-with-iphone-5-screen-size)

I currently have my app on the App store but if i look it in iphone 5 its letter boxed and have black region on the top and bottom. I want to take advantage of the full screen without doing much of work. So can anyone explain what's the best way to do it??

Thanks,

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a -568h launch image.

Set your main window frame to the UIScreen mainScreen bounds in your app delegate.

If everything else in your code sizes itself to the size of your views, there shouldn't be much else to do.

This is all covered in the docs and in lots of blog posts all over the web. Google is your friend.