# Xcode 4.5 SplitView broken orientation with iOS 5.1 (working on iOS6 thought)

Tags: orientation, ipad, ios5.1, xcode4.5

I was working on a splitView project when the Xcode was updated to v4.5. Since then autorotation was working perfectly. After the update, autorotation works only for iOS 6. On iOS 5.1 i am stack in Portrait. I have read all possible solutions but nothing seems to be able to fix my problem. Below is what i have done so far:

Checked that All orientations are in my plist.
Replaced `(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`
with

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return TRUE;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

I added the below snippet in the app delegate

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
    {
        return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
    }
```

I show in another answer the below snippet how ever i am not sure how to implement it in a splitView controller

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   ...
   window.rootViewController = topLevelViewController;
   ...
}
```

Can anybody help me out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep the method from iOS 5:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

to continue support for iOS 5. You thus, keep both the new ones for iOS 6 and the old ones for iOS 5. Note that for the UISplitView to rotate in iOS 5 **all** the enclosed view controllers have to have the above method.