# Keep RubyMotion application from rotating

Tags: ios, objective-c, rubymotion

How can I stop a RubyMotion application from rotating?

I tried implementing:

```
def shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(interfaceOrientation) 
  UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight == interfaceOrientation 
end
```

but I want something that is application-wide, is there a method I can set in the `AppDelegate` that will control this throughout the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a good solution here:

[iOS 6 apps - how to deal with iPhone 5 screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396545/ios-6-apps-how-to-deal-with-iphone-5-screen-size/12397738#12397738)

If you'd like to make it more application-wide, I'd recommend creating a module you can include.

```
module Rotation
  # methods here
end

class MyViewController < UIViewController
  include Rotation
end
```

Comment: Thanks Jamon, I ended up implementing `def shouldAutorotate false end` in each controller and in my Rakefile `app.interface_orientations = [:portrait]` Also, great work with ProMotion - excited to start using it.

Answer (score 0):

@Alekx's solution was the best one for me. All I had to do was set...

```
app.interface_orientations = [:portrait]
```

...in my `Rakefile` and voila! No more autorotation.