# Missing Retina 4 launch image. How to ignore this error?

Tags: ios, ios6, retina-display

Updating Xcode with SDK 6.0 gives you an error when trying to compile your project.

Missing Retina 4 launch image. A launch image named “Default-568@2x.png” is required to run at native resolution on Retina 4 devices. Would you like Xcode to add this image for you?

When clicking add, it creates a black launch image of size 640x1136. I know I can easily replace this image with an appropriate one. But XCode is giving me an error and forcing me to have this file. If I don't want to include this, how can I skip this error and just use the shorter launch image already there?

Screenshots: http://spacetech.dk/xcode-missing-retina-4-launch-image.html

Comment: It is forcing you, as Apple wants you to support the new iPhone 5 too. When the launch image is added, the app will switch to a "fluid" layout and adjust where possible to the new iPhone 5's screen resolution.

Comment: It should just be a warning, unless you have "turn all warnings into errors" turned on.

Comment: I have both warnings and errors.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update**: seems like you can’t ignore his error. It will eventually fail when you upload the binary. Just provide the retina image. Users will like it :D

—————

It appears to be just a warning when I added that file **and then later remove it**. This is weirdddd.

FYI, by including a Retina 4-inch launch image file (Default-568h@2x.png) in your target summary, it will force the app to be stretched to full 4-inch display. In order to keep your app to run in 3.5-inch screen mode again, other than **removing the 4-inch image** you also have to **clean your project AND delete the app.

Answer (score 15):

Go to project settings, select **General** tab, and go to section mentioned in below image.
Here, you only need to specify Launch Image from assets. Hope this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can't really ignore this error.  If you do, you will fail product validation anyway.

This is the text of the error you get:

[image]

So add a 568 launch image, there isn't any way around it.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem after I moved my info.plist file into a new group.
To fix the problem I reselected my plist file by clicking the
"Choose Info.plist File..." button under identity in the general tab of the project file

Comment: I like to keep my Info.plist (and other misc files) in a Resources folder. The Info.plist contains metadata about the LaunchScreen storyboard/image. This was just the error Xcode spit out because it couldn't find the Info.plist anymore. I needed to update the Info.plist location in Build Settings after I moved it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you need to provide a set of launch images for your case.

First, go to Launch Image Attributes Inspector and tick desired device orientations for:

iOS 8.0 and later

iOS 7.0 and later

and then provide appropriate image sizes for the empty slots.

For portrait orientation sizes are:

768x1024 - iPad Portrait @1x

1536x2048 - iPad Portrait @2x

640x1136 - Retina 4

640x960 - iPhone Portrait @2x

1242x2208 - Retina HD 5.5"

750x1334 - Retina HD 4.7"

Answer (score 1):

Well, the easiest solution for me was to create the `Launch Screen.storyboard` and specify that. This gets rid of the need for launch images (unless you really want to go through that song and dance).

Specify the following:

[image]

That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue.
I cleaned my projet after uploading my new image 640x1136 and the notification disapeared.  (Product -> clean ).