# How to Suppress Missing Default Launch Image Warning in Xcode 4.5?

Tags: ios, retina-display, xcode4.5

Xcode 4.5 gives a "Retina 4 support" warning if you don't include a "widescreen" default launch image as part of your project.

My problem is that if I don't add the image my app works fine iPhone 5's with the OS adding some letter-boxing to fill in the unused real-estate, but I have a warning I can't get rid of. If I do add an image the app uses the full screen which is a problem (animations that play or start and stop partially offscreen now are onscreen, etc.)

So my question is:

- Is there a way to suppress the "Retina 4 support" warning?
- If not is there a way to add a default image while keeping the app in the non-widescreen "letter-boxed" mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help in answering your question? It looks similar:

[Missing Retina 4 launch image. How to ignore this error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596991/missing-retina-4-launch-image-how-to-ignore-this-error)