# Xcode 11 UILaunchImages has been deprecated, use launch storyboards instead Warning

Tags: ios, xcode11

I just downloaded Xcode 11 Beta 4 and when I want to build my Swift 4 project gives me:

> UILaunchImages has been deprecated, use launch storyboards instead

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Please read the [release notes for Xcode 11 beta 4](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_4_release_notes?language=objc):

> Known Issues
>
> Your app might fail to build if it contains a launch image. The failure message resembles the following: “The launch image set named <image set name> did not have any applicable content.” Launch images are deprecated and should be removed; use a launch storyboard or .xib file instead. (50210495)
>
> Workaround: Clear the build setting ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_LAUNCHIMAGE_NAME.

Comment: Please note that Apple is going to completely remove support for launch images in the near future. You really should migrate to a launch screen storyboard. You will have no choice eventually.

Comment: THANK YOU. Finding that setting was not obvious.

Comment: Could you please help me ho to show launchImage from assets in Xcode 11 project. In targets launch image catalog asset is missing. How could I user launch image now.

Comment: Thank You. Solved my issue.

Comment: @shashiGupta please use link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58186505/xcode-launch-image-source

Comment: I was getting build warnings about launch images being deprecated even though I had a launch storyboard.  Plus deleting my legacy launch images in my asset catalog resulted in a build error. Clearing the ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_LAUNCHIMAGE_NAME build setting solved the problems.

Answer (score 48):

1. Xcode -> File -> New -> File... -> Launch Screen.
2. Select Target -> Build Settings -> Search "LaunchImage" & delete string from (Debug and Release) Asset Catalog Launch Image Set Name.
3. Select "Assets.xcassets" & remove LaunchImage from it.
4. Build & Run.......enjoy

Comment: I did all of these but old launch image is still appearing as before. Yes, I did a Clean Build Folder first.  And closed Xcode and restarted.

Comment: Fixed. Had to go to General tab in the Targets settings, and under App Icons and Launch Images choose my new launch screen in the Launch Screen File drop-down box.

Comment: I did this and app started with black screen.

Comment: I needed to do this too or else I got a new error warning me I was missing a launch image.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42491551/957245

Answer (score 31):

- add a new storyboard to your project
- name it LaunchScreen.storyboard and save
- add a new view controller to your LaunchScreen, add an imageView, and
  reference your launch image
- make LaunchScreen.storyboard your initial view controller in
  the Attributes Inspector (make sure to uncheck the old initial view
  controller)
- in your General settings (App Icons and Launch Images) in the Launch Screen File dropdown, select LaunchScreen

After testing, to get rid of compiler warnings, delete the LaunchImage folder in Images.xcassets, and in Build Settings, delete LaunchImage (in Debug and Release) from Asset Catalog Launch Image Set Name.

Comment: This is the hardest way possible to create a launch screen storyboard. Xcode actually has two different ways to specifically create a launch screen storyboard which both eliminate most of the steps outlined here.

Comment: @maddy  I'm sure everyone would be happy if you could share your more efficient solution.  After all, that's why we're here, right?

Comment: Xcode -> File -> New -> File... -> Launch Storyboard. That replaces your first 4 bullets.

Comment: In Xcode 11 Release, the entry is File -> New -> File -> Launch Screen

Comment: Providing the steps was helpful as my project already had a `Launch Screen.storyboard` file set up. I needed to follow the 4th and 5th steps to get rid of the warnings. (Xcode 11 release, not beta) Also, note that "General settings" means the Target settings' General tab, while the Build settings tab is under both the Target and Project settings.

Comment: How a single launch screen file will work for different size devices? Just curious

Comment: For tvOS there is no "Launch Screen" option from the File > New > File… menu and "Is Initial View Controller" needs to be set, unlike iOS.

Answer (score 7):

In my case a couple things were happening...

1. I had in my **Info.plist** file **UILaunchImages** which was causing this warning. After deleting it, the warning went away.
2. On the **General** tab of my **ProjectTraget** the **Launch Screen File** was empty. So, adding my launch screen file there from the drop down made my app launch correctly again (This was my main storyboard file).

I hope this helps anyone else having the same warning, and also their app looking letter-boxed.