# Xcode Launch Image Source

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native

I have a very silly question, my xcode project doesn't have setting for **Launch Image Source** , I have already added my splash screen image to **Images.xcassets -> LaunchImage** , but in my project target **General -> App Icon and Launch Images** doesn't have setting for **Launch Image Source**

[image]
[image]

Comment: ...add a LaunchScreen and put the image "LaunchImage" on it

Comment: @TonyMkenu Hi, your suggestion is not the solution that i want. what Im looking is my xcode Launch Image Source disappear, because online research on how to do a splash screen, there are many people able to use Launch Image Source to change their splash image

Comment: I don't know if this has been changed recently but I have the same issue. Perhaps apple have decided that you should be using the xib/storyboard for your launch screen instead of a set of static images.

Comment: facing the same issue actually! got any soultion?

Comment: would love to know as well - is there a solution? Did this change?

Comment: @FeelRightz did you solve it? I'm having the same problem...

Answer (score 39):

I was facing the same issue which I solved this way:

- Select your target in the project navigator and find the *Build Settings* section
- Search for the *Asset Catalog Compiler* options
- Go to the *Asset Catalog Launch Image Set Name* option and set its value to the name of the iOS launch image you created. If you went with the default name, then this value would simply be *LaunchImage*.

If the new launch screens do not show, it might help to delete your app and install it again.

Also make sure the Launch Screen File option in your target's General Settings is blank.

[image: Launch Image Settings]

Comment: I had to also select "All" tab to make "Asset Catalog Launch Image Set Name" appear. But, it was really helpful. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks @user9773845 for your kind help!

Comment: Sad, this is deprecated now. I really needed this.

Comment: @shrishailsh Please let me know if you found a solution to your problem, spent a full day on this already :-( Thanks!

Comment: @WesleyBarnes Nope. I used launchscreen.storyboard and placed my logo at center.

Comment: @shrishailsh Thank you, I figured that out too.

Comment: @WesleyBarnes great!