# Launch Image source in xcode did not show

Tags: objective-c, ios13, xcode11

In my xcode 11.5, I am not able to see Launch Image Source from path **Target->General->App icons and Launch Images-> Launch image source**

[image]

I have referred following link but it does not help me.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58186505/xcode-launch-image-source)

I have added below 2 lines of code into my info.plist file to provide larger screen support.

```
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>LaunchScreen</string>
```

I have multiple targets in my application. So, each target has different splash screen. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Unclear what the question is. Launch images no longer exist. You must use a storyboard or xib.

Comment: @matt: How can I use storyboard?

Comment: If you have added the `<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key><string>LaunchScreen</string>` correctly to the _Info.plist_, and if you actually _have_ a storyboard called _LaunchScreen.storyboard_ as part of your target, you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple Launch Screen Target.storyboards and you can add respective Launch Screen storyboard to respective target under File Inspector. Also you can create multiple Assets.xcassets for each target under different folder and add images specific
to each target. And add Assets.xcassets to respective target under File Inspector.