# Missing Launch Images Source in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, launchimage

I am trying to set Launc Images Source, but I cannot see it on General > Target > App Icons and Launch Images.

I should have:

[image]

But on my Xcode I have:

[image]

Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 11 UILaunchImages has been deprecated, use launch storyboards instead Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57084407/xcode-11-uilaunchimages-has-been-deprecated-use-launch-storyboards-instead-warn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is deprecated in Xcode 11. Use `launchscreen.storyboard` instead. Here is the [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes?preferredLanguage=occ) for reference.