# Godot ios export warning in Xcode: 'uilaunchimages' has been deprecated, use launch storyboards instead

Tags: ios, export, godot4

I am using Godot 4.1.stable and Xcode 14.3.1 and when I build my exported project in Xcode I see this warning:

> 'uilaunchimages' has been deprecated, use launch storyboards instead.

How can I remove it?

I see [an old solution for Xcode 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57084407/xcode-11-uilaunchimages-has-been-deprecated-use-launch-storyboards-instead-warn), I would like to solve it directly in Godot.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is obvious when you see it, it took me some time to figure out, so I put it here for the next person googling for this:

Just check the `Project > Export Storyboard > Use Launch Screen Storyboard`

[image]