# iPhone 5 screen height 480 instead of 568?

Tags: ios5, iphone-5

I wan't to make an app that is compatible with an iOS version as low as 5.0, but still keep it to stretch to the iPhone 5 size. I figured I made 3 different storyboards: one for iPad, iPhone and iPhone 5. I used

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5-widescreen-devices) question

It was very strange when it didn't enter this code

```
if (IS_IPHONE_5 && UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
```

So, I figured to print the screen size to the console, using this code:

```
NSLog(@"%f", [UIScreen mainscreen].bounds.size.height);
```

Oddly, it gave me the output of

```
480.000000
```

instead of 568.f like it should be on a 4-inch device.

**Things that might be the problem:**

1. I'm using the iPhone simulator, sorry I don't have an iPhone 5
2. The app is iOS 5 compatible, which might be the problem

Note: I've tried on 4.6, and it still doesn't work

Comment: Please edit your question title to be descriptive of the problem you're trying to solve!

Comment: Ok, sorry, It should be fixed by now, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Are you actually using 568 pixels in your app and do they get filled? My guess would be that the User Interface(!) size get returned, not the actual hardware dimensions. But I haven't touched those APIs for some time now, I might be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app is not iPhone 5 compatible. Hence, when you run the app on the iPhone 5 simulator, the compatibility mode for 3.5-inch screen turns on automatically, and your app doesn't occupy the entire screen.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396143/how-to-add-iphone-5-large-screen-support-to-ios-apps-in-xcode) you can see how to add iPhone 5 compatability to your app.

Comment: Wow, only setting launch image fixed it, thanks for the tip :D