# ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0) & ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0) not working

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, xcode5, ios8, xcode6

For some reason this won't work since I updated to the latest xcode with iOS 8. it doesn´t recognize 
`([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0)` &

`([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0)`

```
// Indicates game is running on iPad
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    CCLOG(@"Running on iPad");
    // it doesn´t recognize this any more
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0) {
        CCLOG(@"Running on iPad Retina");
    } else {
        CCLOG(@"Running on iPad 2");
    }      
} else {
    CCLOG(@"Running on iPhone");
    // it doesn´t recognize this any more
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0) {
        CCLOG(@"Running on iPhone 5");
    } else {
        CCLOG(@"Running on iPhone 4/4S");
    }
}
```

Comment: which devices did you used? did you tried this `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0` on iPad Retina?

Comment: Don't compare floating point numbers without an epsilon ;). Dunno if this is the error here but you should never do that.

Comment: @WaqasRaja I tried all simulators... ipad 2, ipad air, ipad retina, iphone 4s, iphone 5, iphone 5s, iphone 6, iphone 6 plus.

when running on ipad, they all go the ipad 2 part

when running on iphone, they all go to the iphone 4/4s part.

Comment: UPDATE: for some reason it started to work now for the ipad retina simulator... but still not for the iphone 5/iphone5s/iphone6/iphone6plus

Comment: bounds.height it's a float number, you can try to transform it in an Integer before to compare it:  NSInteger screenHeight_Int=screenHeight; and compare this number if (screenHeight_Int==568)... etc

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the support for the iPhone 5. For this purpose you need to add a launch image named as `Default-568h@2x.png` to your project. Without this image iOS runs the app in compatibility mode i.e. height = 468

This issue is asked earlier in other questions

[how-to-add-iphone-5-large-screen-support-to-ios-apps-in-xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396143/how-to-add-iphone-5-large-screen-support-to-ios-apps-in-xcode)

[How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

Comment: I know that. I´m already using a launch image named Default-568h@2x.png. I have been using that since iOS 6... what I mean is, everything was working fine until I updated from Xcode 5 to Xcode 6. then the problems started

Comment: Update: I just tried my code on Xcode 5.1 and [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0 was working perfectly. What in Xcode 6 is causing this issue and how do I solve it?