# iOS App no on full screen in iPhone 5

Tags: ios, iphone-5

When my App runs on the iPhone 5 it's not displayed in full screen, rather in the size of an iPhone 4.

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Use the launch image for your app, or use launch nib file and this should be fixed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add iPhone 5 large screen support to iOS apps in Xcode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396143/how-to-add-iphone-5-large-screen-support-to-ios-apps-in-xcode)

Comment: It fixed the problem, thanks Guys! But it should delay the opening time of the app, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)